# Creating a custom object on component installation

Tags: lightning-aura-components, soql, custom-object

I have seen that when I install custom apps in my organization a custom object prefix__name__c is created. I assume they are created once the app is installed. I am currently developing a lightning component and I would also want a prefix__name__c object to be created once the component is installed in any organization so I could store custom values in it. How can I do this?

Comment: Is this for an AppExchange app, or for an enterprise customer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a [Package](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sharing_apps.htm&type=5). A package is a container for something as small as an individual component or as large as a set of related apps. After creating a package, you can distribute it to other Salesforce users and organizations, including those outside your company.

So when you install a package you can add object, fields and component in that. When you install that package in another org there you will get all those components which are part of package.

[An Introduction to Packaging](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Packaging)